# Yosemite window close button off center?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I just updated my 13" MacBook Air (early 2014) to OS X Yosemite. The close button on the semaphore buttons at the top-left of the window has the `x` in it off center! That's not something I expect from Apple! It looked fine in Mavericks. I don't have this issue with my MacBook Pro at work, since that one has a Retina display. I Googled for it and some people report the same thing, but nobody says anything about fixing it. Has Apple acknowledged this and plans to fix it? I used Linux in the past and I'm seriously considering installing Linux on this machine due to this.

Changing the colors to graphite centers the `x`, but I don't like graphite. Please help

Comment: You're considering switching your entire operating system based on a misaligned x in a 16 pixel circle? FWIW, unable to reproduce.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the mis-aligned x.

Comment: This is the same thing: http://www.robbert.org/2014/10/the-off-center-close-button/

Comment: A few things: Apple rarely acknowledges bugs until they are already fixed, and even then they don't usually give details about what bugs were fixed, instead citing generic "improvements" in release notes. So with something this trivial (which, in the grand scheme of things, it is), you're never going to see any sort of acknowledgement from Apple, even if they consider it a bug. Second, as the link you provided states, it is likely an issue with sub-pixel rendering. It may take more effort than its worth to fix on non-Retina displays. That's assuming it's affecting everybody. [continued]

Comment: As I said, I'm not seeing any issues. I took a screenshot and zoomed all the way in, and the x was perfectly centered in both the Graphite and Blue color schemes. Finally, while I understand something like that could be an annoyance, I'm not sure what you gain by changing your entire OS due to a few mis-aligned pixels.

Comment: It works fine in my machine at work which has a retina display. It makes me sad. It's more like not switching to OS X, than switch to Linux.

Comment: The Retina display more closely matches physical pixels to rendered pixels which would explain why this is not occurring on a Retina display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your display is made up of pixels which are each made up of 3 subpixels, red, green, and blue. (This is the LCD part in the picture below.) Unfortunately, since red is on the left, it may look a little off center.

[image: display]

Here's a screenshot of the button:

[image: screenshot]

and here's what it looks like on my display:

[image: real]

It would have been difficult for Apple to avoid this issue while still having the close button red. Graphite fixes this because the button is no longer red, and each of the subpixels is equal, so it doesn't look like it's shifted to the left.

In Mavericks, the button was a bit less saturated and a bit subtler, so that may be the reason why it seems to be a problem in Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

If you wear glasses, you may be experiencing chromatic aberration. Nice article about it here: [The off-center close button](http://www.robbert.org/2014/10/the-off-center-close-button/)